# Convertir de String a ImageIcon en Java Netbeans

Tags: java

quisiera saber como convertir de `String` a `ImageIcon` en java.

al momento de cerrar el programa guardo información en un txt, al principio me lo guarda bien.

El problema es cuando quiero volver a leer lo que se almacena en el txt, tengo una lista en la cual inserta todo lo que encuentra.

Pero me da error porque le mando un parámetro de tipo `ImagenIcon` y lo que me devuelve el txt es un String y no sé como convertir.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner la parte de tu código donde ejecutas esa acción? Sería más fácil a la hora de ayudarte.

Comment: ¿Guardas una imagen como String? No dudo que la puedas escribir, pero lo de leerla me recuerda [a esto](http://dilbert.com/strip/1996-02-22).